# Soundcloud player widget cripples page

Tags: html, iframe, soundcloud

I have got a soundcloud player widget on a page and it is causing the page to run extremely slowly. Cursors take ages to change when hovering over buttons and other functionality on the page becomes unusable whenever the song is playing. Everything works normally when the song is stopped.

Even this simple HTML page has the problem, as can be seen by the very slow change of cursor on hovering over the player buttons. I have tried it on a PC and an iMac with various browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F61858057&amp;auto_play=true&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=ff6c00"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone else had this problem recently? Can anyone at Soundcloud shed some light on this?

Comment: Thank you very much for reporting this, it should be fixed now.

Comment: here's a link to working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wxKZG